# core java Filemanager with index which allows us to compete the following things

Tags: java, collections

help  me to find out this........
How to get the list of files using core java concepts with index?
for example a folder may contains the files and sub folder and the files.now the output should come as..

----Output---

enter the path:e:/gk/demo

```
1.work

  1.1 examples

        1.1.1 math.java
        1.1.2 math.class
        !!
        !!

        !!
  1.2 practice

        1.2.1 .....extensions.
1.2.6.3 means 1st folder and 2nd subfolder in the main folder 1and 6th is the subfolder of 2nd sub folder and so on......
```

Tree representation of the folders

1(main folder)

```
 |------->2(sub folder)
      |
      |-------->6(sub folder of 2)
                  |
                  |------------>3
n.1 

        n.1 file1
        n.2 subfolder..
        n.2.1 file1.
        n.2.2 file2.
```

\\Menu:////

1. copy(copy the file by taking the index have been mentioned)
2. delete(delete the file by taking the index have been mentioned)
3. rename(rename the file by taking the index have been mentioned)
4. exit.

The code I have been tried is..to rename the index ..is..

import java.io.File;

import java.io.*;

import java.util.*;

import java.lang.String;

public class RenameIndex

{

```
public void renameIndex(HashMap<String, String> hash)

{

    try

    {
        BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        System.out.print("Please enter the index to be renamed : ");

        String old_name = buffer.readLine();
```

/********************************************************************************/
            String index[]=old_name.split("\.");

```
        for(int i=0;i<index.length;i++)
        {
            Object object = hash.get(index[i]);
            String string = (String)object;
            File oldfile = new File(string);

            System.out.println(index[i]+"\n"+oldfile.getName());
            System.out.println("index length is:"+index.length);
```

/********************************************************************************/

```
            if(!oldfile.exists())
            {
                System.out.println("File or directory does not exist.");
            }
            else
            {
                /*********************************************************/
                if(i<index.length)
                {
                    if(oldfile.isFile())
                    {
                        String path = oldfile.getParent();
                        System.out.print("please enter the new file or directory name : ");
                        String name = buffer.readLine();
                        String newname = path + "/" + name;
                        File newfile = new File(newname);
                        System.out.println("Old File or directory name : " + oldfile);
                        System.out.println("New File or directory name : " + newfile);
                        boolean Rename = oldfile.renameTo(newfile);

                        if(!Rename)
                        {
                            System.out.println("File or directory does not rename successfully.");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            System.out.println("File or directory rename is successfully.");
                        }

                        System.out.println("This is file");
                    }
                    else if(oldfile.isDirectory())
                    {
                        if(i+1==index.length)
                        {
                            String path = oldfile.getParent();
                            System.out.print("please enter the new file or directory name : ");
                            String name = buffer.readLine();
                            String newname = path + "/" + name;
                            File newfile = new File(newname);
                            System.out.println("Old File or directory name : " + oldfile);
                            System.out.println("New File or directory name : " + newfile);
                            boolean Rename = oldfile.renameTo(newfile);

                            if(!Rename)
                            {   
                                System.out.println("File or directory does not rename successfully.");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                            System.out.println("File or directory rename is successfully.");

                            }
                        }
```

/***************************subdirectory and files***********************/
                            else
                            {
                                System.out.println("This is a sub directory");
                            }
/***************************subdirectory and files***********************/
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            System.out.println("Access Denied");
                        }
                    }

```
            /*********************************************************/

            }
        }//for ending
    }

    catch(NullPointerException e)
    {
        System.out.println("No file name is existed"+e);
    }

    catch(IOException ioe)
    {
        System.out.println("No file name is existed"+ioe);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Please show the code you have tried, if yes, any errors you are facing?

Comment: Please help us answer your question by posting your code as well !!!

Comment: Take a look at [java.io.File](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html), [Basic I/O](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/index.html) and [File I/O](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileio.html) and if you're really stuck, [Apache Common IO](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/)

Answer (score 0):

I thought it would be an easy answer, but it took longer than i thought.

The following code is written in Java Processing, so first the constructors, then void setup(), then that's it!

```
ArrayList directoryListing = new ArrayList();

void crawler( String indexer, String path) {
  File[] listFiles = new File(path).listFiles(); 
  for (int i = 0; i < listFiles.length; i++) {
    directoryListing.add(indexer+""+i+".\t"+listFiles[i].getAbsoluteFile().toString());
  }
}

void setup() {
  crawler("", "C:/Temp/MKV Extract");
  int j=0;
  while (j < directoryListing.size ()) {      
    String[] list = split(directoryListing.get(j++).toString(), "\t");
    if (new File(list[1]).isDirectory()) {
      crawler(list[0], list[1]);
    }
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < directoryListing.size(); i++) {
    println(directoryListing.get(i).toString());
  }
  exit();
}
```

And it gives as result :

```
0.  C:\Temp\MKV Extract\!!ReadMeFirst!!.txt
1.  C:\Temp\MKV Extract\base64tool.exe
2.  C:\Temp\MKV Extract\cmd.bat
3.  C:\Temp\MKV Extract\cygz.dll
4.  C:\Temp\MKV Extract\doc
5.  C:\Temp\MKV Extract\examples
6.  C:\Temp\MKV Extract\extract.bat
7.  C:\Temp\MKV Extract\Formats.txt
8.  C:\Temp\MKV Extract\libcharset.dll
9.  C:\Temp\MKV Extract\libebml.dll
10. C:\Temp\MKV Extract\libiconv.dll
11. C:\Temp\MKV Extract\libmatroska.dll
12. C:\Temp\MKV Extract\matroskalogo_big.ico
13. C:\Temp\MKV Extract\MKVextGUI.cfg
14. C:\Temp\MKV Extract\mkvextract.exe
15. C:\Temp\MKV Extract\MKVextractGUI.exe
16. C:\Temp\MKV Extract\mkvinfo.exe
17. C:\Temp\MKV Extract\mkvmerge.exe
18. C:\Temp\MKV Extract\mkxuncat.exe
19. C:\Temp\MKV Extract\mmg.exe
20. C:\Temp\MKV Extract\wxbase253u_gcc_custom.dll
21. C:\Temp\MKV Extract\wxmsw253u_core_gcc_custom.dll
22. C:\Temp\MKV Extract\wxmsw253u_html_gcc_custom.dll
4.0.    C:\Temp\MKV Extract\doc\base64tool.html
4.1.    C:\Temp\MKV Extract\doc\ChangeLog.txt
4.2.    C:\Temp\MKV Extract\doc\COPYING.txt
4.3.    C:\Temp\MKV Extract\doc\images
4.4.    C:\Temp\MKV Extract\doc\mkvextract.html
4.5.    C:\Temp\MKV Extract\doc\mkvinfo.html
4.6.    C:\Temp\MKV Extract\doc\mkvmerge-gui.hhc
4.7.    C:\Temp\MKV Extract\doc\mkvmerge-gui.hhk
4.8.    C:\Temp\MKV Extract\doc\mkvmerge-gui.hhp
4.9.    C:\Temp\MKV Extract\doc\mkvmerge-gui.html
4.10.   C:\Temp\MKV Extract\doc\mkvmerge.html
4.11.   C:\Temp\MKV Extract\doc\mmg.html
4.12.   C:\Temp\MKV Extract\doc\README.txt
4.13.   C:\Temp\MKV Extract\doc\README.Windows.txt
5.0.    C:\Temp\MKV Extract\examples\example-chapters-1.xml
5.1.    C:\Temp\MKV Extract\examples\example-chapters-2.xml
5.2.    C:\Temp\MKV Extract\examples\example-cue-sheet-1.cue
5.3.    C:\Temp\MKV Extract\examples\example-tags-2.xml
5.4.    C:\Temp\MKV Extract\examples\example-timecodes-v1.txt
5.5.    C:\Temp\MKV Extract\examples\example-timecodes-v2.txt
5.6.    C:\Temp\MKV Extract\examples\matroskachapters.dtd
5.7.    C:\Temp\MKV Extract\examples\matroskatags.dtd
4.3.0.  C:\Temp\MKV Extract\doc\images\addingremovingattachments.gif
4.3.1.  C:\Temp\MKV Extract\doc\images\addremovefiles.gif
4.3.2.  C:\Temp\MKV Extract\doc\images\attachmentoptions.gif
4.3.3.  C:\Temp\MKV Extract\doc\images\audiotrackoptions.gif
4.3.4.  C:\Temp\MKV Extract\doc\images\chaptereditor.gif
4.3.5.  C:\Temp\MKV Extract\doc\images\jobmanager.gif
4.3.6.  C:\Temp\MKV Extract\doc\images\movietitle.gif
4.3.7.  C:\Temp\MKV Extract\doc\images\muxingwindow.gif
4.3.8.  C:\Temp\MKV Extract\doc\images\selectmkvmergeexecutable.gif
4.3.9.  C:\Temp\MKV Extract\doc\images\splitting.gif
4.3.10. C:\Temp\MKV Extract\doc\images\textsubtitlestrackoptions.gif
4.3.11. C:\Temp\MKV Extract\doc\images\trackselection.gif
4.3.12. C:\Temp\MKV Extract\doc\images\videotrackoptions.gif
```

Edited, the code is now shorter.

Comment: Please find out the ...Operations those are,
1.copying the file by taking the index as..5.2.3.1

2. rename the file by taking the index as...7.3.6.3

Comment: The problem with creating a GUI, is that it's never correct. Also, i would rather create a GUI in Java Processing instead of traditional Java. In the code above, the Arraylist contains all the indexes and filenames/folders, from here it's easy to add copy, rename, delete, etc.

Comment: The program you have given is not executing It is giving errors..Those are

IndexGeneration.java:24: error: cannot find symbol
                String[] list = split(directoryListing.get(j++).toString(), "\t");
                                ^
  symbol:   method split(String,String)
  location: class IndexGeneration
Note: IndexGeneration.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
3 errors

Comment: replace 'String[] list = split(directoryListing.get(j++).toString(), "\t");' with: String[] list = directoryListing.get(j++).toString().split("\t");

Comment: Thanks .....it is sucessfully compiled but it is giving exceptin....thatis...
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
        at IndexGeneration.setup(MainIndexGene.java:29)
        at MainIndexGene.main(MainIndexGene.java:45)

Comment: The program is .. as follows....
class IndexGeneration
{
 ArrayList directoryListing = new ArrayList();

 void crawler( String indexer, String path)
 {
  File[] listFiles = new File(path).listFiles(); 
  for (int i = 0; i < listFiles.length; i++) 
  {
   directoryListing.add(indexer+""+i+".\t"+listFiles[i].getAbsoluteFile().toString());
   }
 }

Comment: void setup() 
 {
   crawler("", "e:/gk/demo");
   int j=0;
   while (j < directoryListing.size ()) 
   {      
  String[] list = directoryListing.get(j++).toString().split("\t");
  
  if (new File(list[j]).isDirectory()) 
  {
   crawler(list[0], list[j]);
  }

   }
 
 }

}

Comment: class MainIndexGene
{
 public static void main(String args[])
 {
  IndexGeneration ig = new IndexGeneration();
  ig.setup();

 }
}

Comment: The problem is, this is written in Java Processing. So far i can tell, all you need to do is put everything from void setup() into void main. All you need to do is to make sure that the constructors are initialized and that the method crawler is visible from void main.

Comment: Thank you...I have executed that. Please tell me how to go for index like 5.2.1.3 to rename or delete or copy the file or folder.

Comment: The index and the description are in the arraylist. You first have to make a inputbox of some kind to get the index number. Then search through the arraylist till the input equals the index. Then you can do whatever you want, like copy, rename or delete. The problem is to make this visually, because the arraylist can be very large. There is not a easy way to display them all.